# "500 Internal Server Error During Sign-Up"

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am getting error when i tried to signup in my django project,
error is given below,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHZjm.png)

The `urls.py`, `views.py`, `templates` and all the related files and code are provided below. May you please check it and tell me why I am getting this error?

```py
# urls.py

from django.urls import path
from . import views


app_name = "users"
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.AccountView.as_view(), name="account"),
    path('profile/', views.profile_view, name="profile"),
    path('sign-up', views.SignUpView.as_view(), name="sign-up"),
    path('sign-in', views.SignInView.as_view(), name="sign-in"),
    path('sign-out', views.sign_out, name="sign-out"),
]
```

```
# views.py

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

from django_google_api.mixins import (
    AjaxFormMixin,
    reCAPTCHAValidation,
    FormErrors,
    RedirectParams,
)

from .forms import (
    UserForm,
    UserProfileForm,
    AuthForm,
)

result = "Error"
message = "There was an error, please try again"


class AccountView(TemplateView):
    '''
    Generic FormView with our mixin to display user account page
    '''
    template_name = "users/account.html"

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)



def profile_view(request):
    '''
    function view to allow users to update their profile
    '''
    user = request.user
    up = user.userprofile

    form = UserProfileForm(instance = up) 

    if request.is_ajax():
        form = UserProfileForm(data = request.POST, instance = up)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save()
            obj.has_profile = True
            obj.save()
            result = "Success"
            message = "Your profile has been updated"
        else:
            message = FormErrors(form)
        data = {'result': result, 'message': message}
        return JsonResponse(data)

    else:

        context = {'form': form}
        context['google_api_key'] = settings.GOOGLE_API_KEY
        context['base_country'] = settings.BASE_COUNTRY

        return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)



class SignUpView(AjaxFormMixin, FormView):
    '''
    Generic FormView with our mixin for user sign-up with reCAPTURE security
    '''

    template_name = "users/sign_up.html"
    form_class = UserForm
    success_url = "/"

    #reCAPTURE key required in context
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["recaptcha_site_key"] = settings.RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY
        return context

    #over write the mixin logic to get, check and save reCAPTURE score
    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super(AjaxFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)  
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            token = form.cleaned_data.get('token')
            captcha = reCAPTCHAValidation(token)
            if captcha["success"]:
                obj = form.save()
                obj.email = obj.username
                obj.save()
                up = obj.userprofile
                up.captcha_score = float(captcha["score"])
                up.save()
                
                login(self.request, obj, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')

                #change result & message on success
                result = "Success"
                message = "Thank you for signing up"

                
            data = {'result': result, 'message': message}
            return JsonResponse(data)

        return response




class SignInView(AjaxFormMixin, FormView):
    '''
    Generic FormView with our mixin for user sign-in
    '''

    template_name = "users/sign_in.html"
    form_class = AuthForm
    success_url = "/"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super(AjaxFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)  
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            #attempt to authenticate user
            user = authenticate(self.request, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(self.request, user, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
                result = "Success"
                message = 'You are now logged in'
            else:
                message = FormErrors(form)
            data = {'result': result, 'message': message}
            return JsonResponse(data)
        return response




def sign_out(request):
    '''
    Basic view for user sign out
    '''
    logout(request)
    return redirect(reverse('users:sign-in'))
```

```
# mixin.py

from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import requests
import json
import datetime
from humanfriendly import format_timespan
from django.http import JsonResponse


def is_ajax(request):
    return request.META.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest'

def FormErrors(*args):
    '''
    Handles form error that are passed back to AJAX calls
    '''
    message = ""
    for f in args:
        if f.errors:
            message = f.errors.as_text()
    return message
    

def reCAPTCHAValidation(token):

    ''' reCAPTCHA validation '''
    result = requests.post(
        'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
         data={
            'secret': settings.RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY,
            'response': token
         })

    return result.json()



def RedirectParams(**kwargs):
    '''
    Used to append url parameters when redirecting users
    '''
    url = kwargs.get("url")
    params = kwargs.get("params")
    response = redirect(url)
    if params:
        query_string = urlencode(params)
        response['Location'] += '?' + query_string
    return response


class AjaxFormMixin(object):

    '''
    Mixin to ajaxify django form - can be over written in view by calling form_valid method
    '''

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        response = super(AjaxFormMixin, self).form_invalid(form)
        if is_ajax(self.request):
            message = FormErrors(form)
            return JsonResponse({'result':'Error', 'message': message})
        return response

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super(AjaxFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
        if is_ajax(self.request):
            form.save()
            return JsonResponse({'result':'Success', 'message': ""})
        return response


def Directions(*args, **kwargs):
    lat_a = kwargs.get("lat_a")
    long_a = kwargs.get("long_a")
    lat_b = kwargs.get("lat_b")
    long_b = kwargs.get("long_b")
    lat_c = kwargs.get("lat_c")
    long_c = kwargs.get("long_c")
    lat_d = kwargs.get("lat_d")
    long_d = kwargs.get("long_d")

    origin = f'{lat_a},{long_a}'
    destination = f'{lat_b},{long_b}'
    waypoints = f'{lat_c},{long_c}|{lat_d},{long_d}'

    result = requests.get(
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?',
         params={
         'origin': origin,
         'destination': destination,
         'waypoints': waypoints,
         "key": settings.GOOGLE_API_KEY
         })

    directions = result.json()

    if directions["status"] == "OK":

        routes = directions["routes"][0]["legs"]

        distance = 0
        duration = 0
        route_list = []

        for route in range(len(routes)):

            distance += int(routes[route]["distance"]["value"])
            duration += int(routes[route]["duration"]["value"])

            route_step = {
                'origin': routes[route]["start_address"],
                'destination': routes[route]["end_address"],
                'distance': routes[route]["distance"]["text"],
                'duration': routes[route]["duration"]["text"],

                'steps': [
                    [
                        s["distance"]["text"],
                        s["duration"]["text"],
                        s["html_instructions"],

                    ]
                    for s in routes[route]["steps"]]
                }

            
            route_list.append(route_step)
            

    return {
        "origin": origin,
        "destination": destination,
        "distance": f"{round(distance/1000, 2)} Km",
        "duration": format_timespan(duration),
        "route": route_list
        }
```

```html
<!-- sign_up.html -->

{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block extend_head %}
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render={{ recaptcha_site_key }}'></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h3>Django Google API Course - Sign Up</h3>

    <div class="container">
        <form id="signupform" method="POST" action="/sign-up">
            {% csrf_token %}

            <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
            {{ form.first_name }}

            <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
            {{ form.last_name }}

            <label for="username">Username</label>
            {{ form.username }}

            <label for="password1">Password</label>
            {{ form.password1 }}

            <label for="password2">Confirm Password</label>
            {{ form.password2 }}

            {{ form.token }}

            <label class="check-container">Show Passwords
                <input type="checkbox" onclick="showPword()">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>

            <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block extend_footer %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Create a variable that can be used in main.js
        var recaptcha_site_key = '{{ recaptcha_site_key|safe }}';
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

The error

```
Traceback:
Internal Server Error: /sign-up
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\laxma\OneDrive\Desktop\dsa and practice\learning\django\Python Django and Google APIs - Project Tutorial\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\laxma\OneDrive\Desktop\dsa and practice\learning\django\Python Django and Google APIs - Project Tutorial\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\laxma\OneDrive\Desktop\dsa and practice\learning\django\Python Django and Google APIs - Project Tutorial\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\laxma\OneDrive\Desktop\dsa and practice\learning\django\Python Django and Google APIs - Project Tutorial\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\laxma\OneDrive\Desktop\dsa and practice\learning\django\Python Django and Google APIs - Project Tutorial\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 142, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "C:\Users\laxma\OneDrive\Desktop\dsa and practice\learning\django\Python Django and Google APIs - Project Tutorial\django_google_api\users\views.py", line 110, in form_valid
    data = {'result': result, 'message': message}
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'result' where it is not associated with a value
[15/Nov/2023 17:17:05] "POST /sign-up HTTP/1.1" 500 86818
```

I have tried stack overflow solution but they didnt work

Comment: i am developing the django project,
so in the backend(in the terminal) i get the same error as you can see in the traceback

Comment: i think the error is because of  is_ajax() method which i have used in the views.py file,

all the dependencies along with the versions are as follows:

Answer (score 1):

The image hints at `UnboundLocalError at /sign-up/`. **Please, if you have an error: always include the traceback if you have it.** It makes finding the problem so much easier.

Looking at the SignUpView, it seems that `result` and `message` are not set if `captcha["success"]` is False. Add a result and message if the captcha fails:

```
   def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super(AjaxFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)  
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            token = form.cleaned_data.get('token')
            captcha = reCAPTCHAValidation(token)
            if captcha["success"]:
                obj = form.save()
                obj.email = obj.username
                obj.save()
                up = obj.userprofile
                up.captcha_score = float(captcha["score"])
                up.save()
                
                login(self.request, obj, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')

                #change result & message on success
                result = "Success"
                message = "Thank you for signing up"
            else:
                result = "Nope!"
                message = "Try again!"
            data = {'result': result, 'message': message}
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

**UPDATE**

By assinging values to `result` and `message` in a method, you are shadowing the global variables. Please read: https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/

> If you try to assign a value to a global name inside a function, then you’ll be creating that name in the function’s local scope, shadowing or overriding the global name.

The global variables `result` and `message` are no longer available in the method, so `data = {'result': result, 'message': message}` throws an exception if you don't declare those variables in the local scope.

If you want to keep your global default messages, you can assign them to local variables:

```
DEFAULT_REASON = "Error"
DEFAULT_MESSAGE = "There was an error, please try again"

...

class SignUpView():
   def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super(AjaxFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)  
        reason = DEFAULT_REASON
        message = DEFAULT_MESSAGE
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            token = form.cleaned_data.get('token')
            captcha = reCAPTCHAValidation(token)
            if captcha["success"]:
                obj = form.save()
                obj.email = obj.username
                obj.save()
                up = obj.userprofile
                up.captcha_score = float(captcha["score"])
                up.save()

                login(self.request, obj, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')

                #change result & message on success
                result = "Success"
                message = "Thank you for signing up"
            data = {'result': result, 'message': message}
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: and sir i have added the traceback ,You may take help from it

Comment: But sir ,If you see the views.py file , i have added global request and message so if captcha is not true, then default message is passed

Comment: But in the method, you're assigning values to result and message, which turns them into local variables. I have updated my answer, please read that.

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your code is related to the variable scoping. In the `form_valid` method of your `SignUpView` class, you are trying to access the `result` and `message` variables without defining them within the method. This is causing the `UnboundLocalError`. To fix this, you should define the `result` and `message` variables before the `if captcha["success"]` block, and provide default values in case the conditions inside the block are not met. Here's the corrected code:

```py
def form_valid(self, form):
    response = super(AjaxFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)  

    # Default values
    result = "Error"
    message = "There was an error, please try again"

    if self.request.is_ajax():
        token = form.cleaned_data.get('token')
        captcha = reCAPTCHAValidation(token)
        if captcha["success"]:
            obj = form.save()
            obj.email = obj.username
            obj.save()
            up = obj.userprofile
            up.captcha_score = float(captcha["score"])
            up.save()
            
            login(self.request, obj, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')

            # Change result & message on success
            result = "Success"
            message = "Thank you for signing up"

        data = {'result': result, 'message': message}
        return JsonResponse(data)

    return response
```

This ensures that the variables `result` and `message` are defined in the correct scope, avoiding the `UnboundLocalError`.

Also, it seems that in the `SignInView` and `profile_view` functions, the `result` variable doesn't have a default value, and there's a potential for an `UnboundLocalError` to be raised if the condition for setting result to "Success" is not met. You will need to also add a default for `result` to prevent `UnboundLocalError` in these views.

```py
def profile_view(request):
    '''
    function view to allow users to update their profile
    '''
    user = request.user
    up = user.userprofile

    form = UserProfileForm(instance=up)

    # Initialize result with a default value
    result = "Error"
    message = "There was an error, please try again"

    if request.is_ajax():
        form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST, instance=up)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save()
            obj.has_profile = True
            obj.save()
            # Update result on success
            result = "Success"
            message = "Your profile has been updated"
        else:
            message = FormErrors(form)
        data = {'result': result, 'message': message}
        return JsonResponse(data)

    else:
        context = {'form': form}
        context['google_api_key'] = settings.GOOGLE_API_KEY
        context['base_country'] = settings.BASE_COUNTRY
        return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

And in the `SignInView`

```py
class SignInView(AjaxFormMixin, FormView):
    '''
    Generic FormView with our mixin for user sign-in
    '''

    template_name = "users/sign_in.html"
    form_class = AuthForm
    success_url = "/"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super(AjaxFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            # Initialize result with a default value
            result = "Error"
            message = "There was an error, please try again"

            # attempt to authenticate user
            user = authenticate(self.request, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(self.request, user, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
                # Update result on success
                result = "Success"
                message = 'You are now logged in'
            else:
                message = FormErrors(form)
            data = {'result': result, 'message': message}
            return JsonResponse(data)
        return response
```